# Roscd is not working on fuerte

Tags: ros, roscd, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to use Roscd in Ubuntu terminal. In return I get "roscd: command not found". Help me please.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39087/roscd-is-not-working-on-fuerte/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While @prince's answer surely will work, I guess the problem is that you don't source `/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash`, assuming you are using Fuerte. Are you maybe sourcing `/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.sh`? Make sure you've set up your environment correctly as described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to run following command

```
source ${ROS_ROOT}/tools/rosbash/rosbash
```

Please refer to following link http://ros.org/wiki/rosbash

[www.ros.org/wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki) has well managed dooumentation for most of the things. It is nice idea to read the documentation if you are new to it and search the forum.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out what my problem was... I did not configure my ros_package_path correctly.

---

Originally posted by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) with karma: 302 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-18**:
Also, if you are using roscd, you need to configure your ros workspace.